# wildcard subdomain in cloudflare zero trust -> tunnel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, mern, cloudflare

I have deployed an application on an Ubuntu virtual server machine and purchased a domain name from Name.com. I have set up Cloudflare with this domain for SSH access, and I can access the virtual machine with a fixed subdomain (e.g., abc.example.com) when i add this in zero trust->tunnel ->access-> public host. However, when I try to use a wildcard subdomain (e.g., *.example.com),
it does not work.I would like to enable wildcard subdomains for SSH access using Cloudflare tunnel. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.